# Objective C - Multithreading issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading

In my app, when user presses on the one of the tabs in `UITabBar`, it takes too much time to load view and show it to the user, so it may be confusing (it's because I load images from the web in the `UITableView`). So, I decided to use multithreading to show view before all the images finished loading.

I am using this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SetsCustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
    // getting url
    NSURL* imgUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[[mainArray objectAtIndex:
                       indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"imageURL"]];
    //put this url and current cell in the dictionary
    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    imgUrl,@"localUrl",cell,@"localCell", nil];
   // multithreading time (calling loadImageWithParams method)
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageWithParams:)
                           withObject:params];
    return cell;
}
-(void)loadImageWithParams:(NSDictionary*)params {
    NSURL* url = [params objectForKey:@"localUrl"];
    cell = [params objectForKey:@"localCell"];
    UIImage* thumb = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    NSDictionary* backParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                   cell,@"localCell",thumb,@"thumb", nil];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:)
                        withObject:backParams waitUntilDone:YES];
}
-(void)setImage:(NSDictionary*)params{
    cell = [params objectForKey:@"localCell"];
    UIImage* thumb = [params objectForKey:@"thumb"];
    [cell.imageView setImage:thumb];
    cell.imageView.hidden = NO;
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
}
```

I have only two cells in the `UITableView` and the problem is that only second cell loads its image. The first cell is still empty. However, if I scroll the `UITableView` until the first cell is no longer visible, and it calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` again, first cell gets its image.

I have also tried to make multithreading with `NSOperationQueue` and `GCD` but have the same results.

It seems like I don't clearly understand how multithreading works but I will be veeeery grateful if someone will point me at my mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to put local images into the table until you get the downloaded ones? I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: No, I just load images from the web. While they are loading, cells are just empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past is to create an NSObject subclass to store the images. Then the datastore for the UITableView is an array of these objects instead of URL paths.

Then you can lazy load the image like this...

ObjectModel.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
```

ObjectModel.m

```
- (UIImage*)image
{
    if (_image == nil) {
        [self downloadImage];
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderImage"];
    }
    return _image;
}

- (void)downloadImage
{
    //Put your async stuff here to download the image then reload the tableView when it's done.
}
```

By doing this you are storing the images on the datastore but also managing the download stuff in its own class and keeping your TVC clean.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're overcomplicating this -- I don't really understand what you're doing with the params dictionary. Why not present the controller, then start your download in viewDidAppear. When the results come back, populate your array with them, and call reloadData. Do the cells have anything in them besides the images that you can load right away?

Comment: Just images.
Yes, looks like I overcomplicated this. Thank you for the solution !

Answer (score 1):

Typical practice for this is to implement a LazyUIImage class which downloads/loads the image in the background.   While the image is downloading, display something like a UIActivityIndicator.  When the image arrives in the LazyUIImage, send out a notification and stop the activity indicator (and remove it from the view perhaps).   For every view controller that contains a LazyUIImage, handle that notification, and e.g., perform [myTable reloadData].   In LazyUIImage, write a method called getImage which returns nil while  the image is loading, and after the image has loaded, return the image.

Edit: actually, if you implement the LazyUIImage as a LazyUIImageView then you don't need to reload anything in containing view controllers: in the LazyUIImageView place a top level background view, and then switch out  the UIActivityIndicator child view for the actual UIImageView once the image finishes downloading.

Answer (score -2):

You need to do Lazy loading stuff.. Search for lazy loading using NSOperationQueue.